# Getting error while loading Sqlite dll in Window 10 mahcine

Tags: c#

We are working on an application which writes and fetches information from SQLite.
We have used the required SQLite dlls.

It is working for Windows 12 R2 machine. But for Windows 10 machine we are getting below error(Both machines are 64-bit machine):

"Operation Completed
An error occurred while connecting to the specified connection details.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
File name: 'System.Data.SQLite.dll'"

In Windows 10 machine explicitly added all the dlls of sqlite exe of 64 bit and it is working
Not sure what could be the issue as it working in WIndows 2012 R2 machine

Tried to find the root cause using Process Manager and Event Viewer but not able to get anything

Comment: Have you tried setting the "Platform Target" in your project properties to "x64" (not Any CPU)?

Comment: Currently the application runs in 64-bit mode. However on WIndows 7 mahcine we do not see any issue and on WIndows 10 we get an error